# DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --ssh default -t atomiclib

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker

unknown flag: --ssh
See 'docker build --help'.

i am able to do successfully with another system but it is not working on my machine
what is missing?

Comment: the docker version is Docker version 18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a

Comment: In `Docker 18.06.1-ce` you need [`experimental`](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/master/frontend/dockerfile/docs/experimental.md) features enabled and to use [`buildkit`](https://github.com/moby/buildkit).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps different Docker version?

```
docker --version
```

Comment: Docker version 18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a

Comment: On both machines? (your machine and remote machine)